# how to select a item from exist dropdown from excel by phpexcel

Tags: phpexcel

I am trying to export excel

I want to select one item from exist excel dropdown with phpexcel.

but I cann't find any solution to slove this problems.

Someone can help me please. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Data Validation, with the TYPE_LIST option

See `15datavalidation.php` in the `/Examples` folder

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('A7', "List:")
    ->setCellValue('B7', "Item #2")
    ->setCellValue('D2', "Item #1")
    ->setCellValue('D3', "Item #2")
    ->setCellValue('D4', "Item #3")
    ->setCellValue('D5', "Item #4")
    ->setCellValue('D6', "Item #5");

$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('B7')->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
$objValidation->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
$objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
$objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
$objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
$objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
$objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
$objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
$objValidation->setFormula1('$D$2:$D$6');
```

Applies to `Excel5` and `Excel2007` Writers

Comment: Hello Mark! I have the same issue, but when I have generated the excel file it shows me about this file is damaged. What is happening? Some clue? Thanks

Comment: @Freenando - Open the file in a text editor..... look for leading or trailing whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, newlines); look for a BOM header that shouldn't be there; look for any plaintext error messages embedded in the file from your PHP script

Comment: Thank you very much Mark! I have found my problem. It was here $objValidation->setFormula1('$W$1:$W$j'); I used my iterator j and it didn't convert in a number file. I have solved the problem $objValidation->setFormula1('$W$1:$W$'.$j); and it works!